Excel: More efficient way of checking multiple AND in an OR function
I have following code for a checksum in my excel sheet:
=If(Or(And(E5="Other";G5="n.a.");And(E10="Other";G10="n.a."); ANND );"Missing entry";"All good")


Basically if the user selected "Other" in a cell, the user is forced to change the default answer "n.a." to an actual comment.
ANND represents the AND conditions for the 50+ more rows where I would have to check if the condition applies. This naturally slows down excel, so my question is if there is a faster way to check the conditions.
I would prefer to accomplish this without VBA and loops as the user might not feel comfortable using them.

Maybe just a simple COUNTIFS()? I mean, if you have the input in these 50 rows (even with intervals of 5) and you are sure that the combination should never come up: =IF(COUNTIFS(E:E;"Other";G:G;"n.a.");"Missing entry";"All good")

What about conditional formating and highlight the spcific cell that is a problem?

@JvdV That does the trick, many thanks

@Carlini, perfect, I'll answer the question for you to accept it and thus close this thread.

From comment to answer, this is what OP could use:
=IF(COUNTIFS(E:E;"Other";G:G;"n.a.");"Missing entry";"All good")

